# Get product collection from Pager / Product List block

Tags: blocks, product-list

I'm adding a custom block that will reside on frontend pages which contain a Product List (`catalog_category_view`, `catalogsearch_result_index`, etc).  The block needs to know which products are being displayed to the user.

I hoped to find an equivalent of the `current_product` registry item that's used on a product page; however so far I haven't found where I can readily retrieve this.

At the moment I'm handling the `core_block_abstract_to_html_after` event and then getting the collection from the Pager block:

```
public function coreBlockAbstractToHtmlAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
    if (!$block instanceof Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager) {
        return;
    }

    /** @var Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager $list */
    $list = $block;
    $products = $list->getCollection();

    Mage::register('current_products', $products);
}
```

Have I reinvented the wheel?  Is there a built-in option, or a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

STw,i don't  thought that using `core_block_abstract_to_html_after` event,using
`!$block instanceof Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager` ,you did not get *any product collection*,because of:

For every product collection ,***pager block does not called like*** *related product collection at product details page*, *crossell products at checkout page.*

So suggestion to use different for example:

Search & category pages,you can use: [`catalog_block_product_list_collection`](https://github.com/engineyard/magento-ce-1.9/blob/master/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php#L32)

Also,you use [`catalog_product_collection_load_after`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php#L545) event which is called at every product collection.But just be carefull that  **You need fire this event for only frontend Area.** other

> ```
> <config>
>     <frontend>
>         <events>
>             <catalog_product_collection_load_after>
>                 <observers>
>                     <namespace_module>
>                         <class>namespace_module/observer</class>
>                         <method>someMethod</method>
>                     </namespace_module>
>                 </observers>
>             </catalog_product_collection_load_after>
>         </events>
>     </frontend>
> </config>
> ```

**Note: that is my thought.**